# How to test a method that uses async/await?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-2017

I've seen a lot of articles about how use async/await in your unit tests, but my need is the opposite.

How do you write a test for a method that uses async/await?

My spec is not able to reach any code after the 'await' line. Specifically, the spec fails in two ways.

1) `HelloWorld.otherCall` returns undefined instead of the return value I specify

2) `HelloWorld.processResp` never gets called

```
class HelloWorld {

    async doSomething(reqObj) {
        try {
           const val = await this.otherCall(reqObj);
           console.warn(val); // undefined
           return this.processResp(val);
        }
    }

}

describe('HelloWorld test', function () {

    let sut = new HelloWorld(); //gross simplification for demo purposes

    describe('doSomething()', function () {
        beforeEach(function mockInputs() {
           this.resp = 'plz help - S.O.S.';
        });

        beforeEach(function createSpy() {
            spyOn(sut, 'otherCall').and.returnValue( $q.resolve(this.resp) );
            spyOn(sut, 'processResp');
        });

        it('should call otherCall() with proper arguments', function () {
            //this test passes   
        });

        it('should call processResp() with proper arguments', function () {
           sut.doSomething({});
           $rootScope.$apply(); //you need this to execute a promise chain..

           expect(sut.processResp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(this.resp); 
           //Expected spy processResp to have been called with [ 'plz help SOS' ] but it was never called.
        });
    });
});
```

*Running angular 1.5 and jasmine-core 2.6.*

Answer (score 9):

The `.then` of a promise is overloaded to handle either promises or values, and `await` is syntactic sugar for calling `then`.

So there is no reason your spy would be required to return a promise, or even a value. Returning at all, even if `undefined`, should trigger the `await` to fire, and kick off the rest of your `async` function.

I believe your problem is that you are not waiting for the `doSomething` promise to resolve before trying to test what it did. Something like this should get you more in the ballpark.

```
it('should call processResp() with proper arguments', async function () {
   await sut.doSomething({});
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine has [Asynchronous Support](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). You can probably find a solution that way.

Personally, I think you should not test such methods at all.

**Testing state** means we're verifying that the code under test returns the right results.

**Testing interactions** means we're verifying that the code under test calls certain methods properly.

At most cases, testing state is better.

At your example,

```
async doSomething(reqObj) {
    try {
       const val = await this.otherCall(reqObj);
       return this.processResp(val);
    }
}
```

As long as otherCall & processResp are well covered by unit tests your good.

Do something should be covered by e2e tests.

you can read more about it at http://spectory.com/blog/Test%20Doubles%20For%20Dummies